# Deserialise cnn_face_detection_model_v1 in C++

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I'm porting some Python Dlib code over to C++ but the class `cnn_face_detection_model_v1` does not seem to exist in the C++ source code so I'm unable to deserialise the model.

The website lists the class in the C++ class list but it doesn't seem to exist in the dlib source other than in the Python wrapper code.

Can anyone shed any light as to how I can deserialise this model?

(New to Dlib and Python)

Answer (score 0):

You do it like shown in this example: http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp.html